# Caused by: NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type xxx expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, dependency-injection

I have the following code bellow:

```
package far.botshop.backend.controller;

/**
 */
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import far.botshop.backend.storage.StorageService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

@Controller
public class FileUploadController {

    private final StorageService storageService;

    @Autowired
    public FileUploadController(StorageService storageService) {
        this.storageService = storageService;
    }
```

And have the following class created:

```
package far.botshop.backend.storage;

import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;

@ConfigurationProperties("storage")
public class StorageProperties {
    /**
     * Folder location for storing files
     */
    private String location = "upload-dir";

    public String getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    public void setLocation(String location) {
        this.location = location;
    }

}
```

I believe StorageProperties should be easily found, but for some reason I'm getting this error:

> UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name
>   'fileSystemStorageService' defined in file
>   [/home/x/workspace/botshop-backend-java/target/classes/far/botshop/backend/storage/FileSystemStorageService.class]:
>   Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0;
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type
>   'far.botshop.backend.storage.StorageProperties' available: expected at
>   least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add @Component Annotation over StorageProperties class.

Comment: `@ConfigurationProperties` should be used with `@EnableConfigurationProperties`

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to

```
@Autowired
    public FileUploadController(StorageService storageService) {
        this.storageService = storageService;
    }
```

but you haven't defined StorageService as Bean.

So you should add `@Component` annotation or equivalent over the StorageService class.